# RecyclerView onCreateViewHolder position background Color

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I need to set  background color inside `onCreateViewHolder`. 
So, when my `position` is equal to`position % 2 == 0` then set a background Color, else to set another Color.
My background color is standard from all of my rows, that's why i thought to use it inside `onCreateViewHolder` and not `onBindViewHolder`. Correct me if i am wrong. The problem is that when i am using `holder.getAdapterPosition` inside `onCreateViewHolder` it returns `'-1'`. It seems normal to me. But how can i fix that?

```
  @Override
  public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {


    View mView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.inflate_common_item, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolder holder= new ViewHolder(mView);
    if(holder.getAdapterPosition % 2 ==0)
    {
       //Row BackgroundColor to red.
    }
    else
    {
      //Row BackgroundColor to Green.
    }
    return holder;
```

}

So when i use the code above i am getting exception that it is index out of bound.
Is there any way to fix ?

Comment: Do all validation inside `onBindViewHolder()` not inside `onCreateViewHolder`. `holder.getAdapterPosition` will return -1 inside `onCreateViewHolder` because You have just created it .

Comment: Thank you Adm. but isn't useless to repeat color in each row? When the color of my rows is  standard?

Comment: `@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder  holder, int position) {
        if(position % 2 ==0) {
            mView .setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_red));
        } else {
            mView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_green));
        }
    }`

Comment: i think problem is in the getitemcount() method of holder check it properly.

Comment: Your code will look like above .. And i did not get what you have just asked .

Comment: onBindViewHolder it will repeat my background Color, on every scroll right? Why to do that when i know the standar color of all my rows? Isn't it better to set them while they are create? Or there is not way to do that?

Comment: You are setting color as per Even Odd row . And  Since you are using only one view type so you have to do this in `onBindViewHolder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to ideal solution you should write this code in onBindViewHolder to use "getAdapterPosition".

if you want only different background Color of row in onCreateViewHolder than you can try this,This will give you one red color row and one other color row continuously.

you need to create a global variable.

```java
boolean Manual_color = true;

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

    View mView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.inflate_common_item, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolder holder= new ViewHolder(mView);
    if(Manual_color)
    {
       //Row BackgroundColor to red.
       Manual_color = false;
    }
    else
    {
      //Row BackgroundColor to Green.
      Manual_color = true;
    }
    return holder;
}
```

Comment: It works but it mess it up when i am scrolling. Forget it i will accept it as answer. According to ideal solution you should write this code in onBindViewHolder... One last Question. Click listeners are better to be used onCreateViewHolder instead onBindViewHolder?

Comment: click listeners have to be set in onBindViewHolder @Dhi

Comment: Dosent have any performance issue to repeat my click listener every time i am scrolling?

Comment: @Dhi No,don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.inflate_common_item, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(position % 2 ==0) {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(holder.itemView.getContext(), R.color.color_red));
    } else {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(holder.itemView.getContext(), R.color.color_green)); 
    }
}
```

Comment: yes , you have to deal with possition in `onbindviewholder()` . answer seems correct

Answer (score 0):

You can set color to the view that you have inflated.

```
View mView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.inflate_common_item, viewGroup, false);
ViewHolder holder= new ViewHolder(mView);
if(holder.getAdapterPosition % 2 ==0) {
    mView .setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_red));
} else {
    mView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_green));
}
```

Comment: But i am getting error on this line if(holder.getAdapterPosition % 2 ==0)  with the exception above. (it returns -1)

Comment: check if your arraylist is filled or empty.